ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR while changing the Layout in Sitecore Headless SXA 10.3
We are working on Sitecore 10.3 SXA (Headless with Next.js).
While trying to change the layout of a site, we are getting (failed)net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR while accessing the Layout Service.

Are there any configuration settings that need to be adjusted? We have already updated the LayoutPath in Site Settings.
Thanks,
Hari

Do you see any errors in Sitecore logs or event viewer? It will help to troubleshoot what is going wrong. Also as you are saying an error is appearing while changing the layout, can you make sure your components are working fine and they are not causing any issues while serving the layout.

To troubleshoot the ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR when accessing the Layout Service in Sitecore 10.3 SXA (Headless with Next.js), follow these steps:

Double-Check Layout Service Host URL:
Ensure that the layoutServiceHost URL in your site configuration is
correct and points to the appropriate Sitecore instance. IIS
Configuration:

Navigate to IIS Manager.
Go to Your Site.
Click on Bindings.
Select the appropriate binding and click Edit.
Ensure that Require Server Name Indication (SNI) is selected.

Browser Compatibility:
Sometimes browser-specific issues can trigger HTTP/2 errors. Test accessing the
Layout Service using different browsers to determine if the issue is browser-
specific.

Check Your JSS API Key:
Verify that your JSS API key is correctly configured and valid. This is crucial
for authenticating requests to the Layout Service.



There could be many reasons for http2 protocol error, so it will be hard to pinpoint the exact issue, but let me try and see if it helps
Try to disable HTTP/2 protocol on IIS bindings like following

Now, once this is done, try hitting the layout service, it could now give you the actual error if any.
